# How do you create an HTML table in Ruby?

Tags: html, ruby

I want to create a 2x2 table in Ruby in order to output a side-by-side comparison of some XML files. The first row would just be headers, the next row would be the files.

Comment: Ruby or Ruby on Rails?

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified. Ruby

Comment: How much from the xml do you want to display ? all of it ? Do you just want to dump all the XML content on each side, or do you want a visual, line-by-line comparison ?

Comment: I've already taken two xml files, compared & diffed into two separate hashes; removed & added, which I converted back into an XML format. I want to dump the two new XML's, one on each side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, a very simple script like that could do the job, but I might have missed something from your question:

```
# Assuming your xml files are xml1.xml and xml2.xml, this will create an HTML file called result.html containing the HTML table
html = ""
html += "<html>"
html += "<table>"
html += "<tr><td>First XML File</td><td>Second XML file</td></tr>"
html += "<tr>"
html += "<td>"
html += File.read("xml1.xml", :encoding => "UTF-8").encode(:xml => :text)
html += "</td>"
html += "<td>"
html += File.read("xml2.xml", :encoding => "UTF-8").encode(:xml => :text)
html += "</td>"
html += "</tr>"
html += "</table>"
html += "</html>"

%x(echo '#{html}' >> "result.html")
```

If you want to have pretty-indentation on top of that, you can use ruby core REXML::Document which has it built-in. You also have to nest your pretty-indented XML in a pre tag for it to display well:

```
require "rexml/document"

doc1 = REXML::Document.new File.read("xml1.xml", :encoding => "UTF-8")
out1 = ""
doc1.write(out1, 2)

doc2 = REXML::Document.new File.read("xml2.xml", :encoding => "UTF-8")
out2 = ""
doc2.write(out2, 2)

html=""
html += "<html>"
html += "<table>"
html += "<tr><td>First XML File</td><td>Second XML file</td></tr>"
html += "<tr>"
html += "<td><pre>"
html += out1.encode(:xml => :text)
html += "</pre></td>"
html += "<td><pre>"
html += out2.encode(:xml => :text)
html += "</pre></td>"
html += "</tr>"
html += "</table>"
html += "</html>"

%x(echo '#{html}' >> "result.html")
```

Comment: I'm actually having an issue where the XML I read in is not keeping its format. Any ideas?

Comment: What part of the format is lost ? Is it some characters changing ? Or is the indentation not pretty ?

Comment: Indentation is not pretty, it just reads out in one long string with a bunch of breaks in rows